# FRESteamworks implementation for native extension not found for target platform (Mac)

Tags: macos, bash, flash, adt

I'm currently trying to package a flash project using ADT on mac to create a .dmg. I've been able to fix all of the errors with the exception of "The implementation for native extension com.amanitadesign.steam.FRESteamworks could not be found for the target platform.

My descriptor file looks like the following:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

`<extensions>
      <extensionID>com.amanitadesign.steam.FRESteamWorks</extensionID>
 </extensions>`

I am packaging the .dmg with the following bash code:

```
adt -package 
    -storetype pkcs12 
    -keystore myCert.pfx 
    -target native 
    myApp.dmg 
    application.xml
```

Whatever I do I still seem to get the error that it's not found for the target platform. It is usable for Mac OS X but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. For more information on FRESteamworks: https://github.com/Ventero/FRESteamWorks

Answer (score 2):

As I [mention in the README](https://github.com/Ventero/FRESteamWorks#packaging-1), you have to supply the `-extdir` flag to `adt`. The argument for that flag has to be a directory containing the ANE.

For an example, see [my packaging script](https://github.com/Ventero/FRESteamWorks/blob/master/test/bin-debug/packageMac.sh#L14-19) in the same repository.

Comment: Thanks! That error seems to have gone away but now I'm receiving an error: "Included native extension includes a SWF version of 11 which is greater than the root SWF of 10" I'm sure this is something on my side, however I'm jumping into this project without much background knowledge of previous decisions. Do you know what would be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: @CameronBarge You'll have to make sure whatever compiler you're using to compile your application generates an SWF with SWF version >= 11. How that's done depends on what build environment you're using. For mxmlc/asc, just add `-swf-version=11` to the command line flags. For tools like Flash CS/Flash Builder, there's probably a settings for this somewhere in the project settings.